# Inflater button click listener not work

Tags: android, listview, button, onclicklistener, baseadapter

i have one custom listview and i want to give click listener into the Button ui object but it's not working, please kindly go through my below code and suggest me some solution.

```
package com.example.dynamicbutton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      Activity activity;
      ArrayList<String> name;

      ViewHolder holder;

public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> name) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return name.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return name.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return name.size();
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView fruitName;
    Button btnStatus;
}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder") 
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    if (convertView == null) { 
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_layout, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.fruitName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fruit_name);
        holder.btnStatus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_status);

        holder.btnStatus.setText("Like");
        holder.fruitName.setText(name.get(position));

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
        holder.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (holder.btnStatus.getText().toString().equals("Like")) {
                    holder.btnStatus.setText("Unlike");
                }else{
                    holder.btnStatus.setText("Like");
                }
            }
        });

    return convertView;

} }
```

So here in this BaseAdapter i want to give listener to holder.btnStatus but in the list the listener is working on only one row i want to give the listener dynamically.
Please kindly go through my code and suggest me some solution.

Comment: Where you used `ViewHolder setTag()` and `getTag()` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry i also don't know how to use setTag() and getTag() in ViewHolder

Comment: If you will help me about this then it will great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_layout, parent, false);

holder = new ViewHolder();

holder.fruitName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fruit_name);
holder.btnStatus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_status);

holder.btnStatus.setText("Like");
holder.fruitName.setText(name.get(position));
```

To

```
 if (convertView == null) { 
 LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_layout, parent, false);

 holder = new ViewHolder();

holder.fruitName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fruit_name);
holder.btnStatus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_status);

holder.btnStatus.setText("Like");
holder.fruitName.setText(name.get(position));

convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

EDIT2

```
holder.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (holder.btnStatus.getText().toString().equals("Like")) {
                holder.btnStatus.setText("Unlike");
            }else{
                holder.btnStatus.setText("Like");
            }
        }
    });
```

to

```
final ViewHolder holder_fin = holder;

holder_fin.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (holder_fin.btnStatus.getText().toString().equals("Like")) {
                holder_fin.btnStatus.setText("Unlike");
            }else{
                holder_fin.btnStatus.setText("Like");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks i replace to your code but result is same please kindly go through my code again i have post the code.

Comment: There is no exception only in the list the listener is working only for one row, if you click to any button the listener is working only to one row. I want to give individual listener to individual button.

Comment: yes.. its of same type as it was old.. holder_fin will have only one holder for one postion.

Comment: Accept my answer if it is working.. u hv to just click on tick of my answer

Comment: sorry to say bro i am not having that much of reputation to tick your answer.

Comment: reputation is required to upvote answer.. for acceptance no need of reputations..  see here.. for reffrence https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51157895/uqJeW.png